# <Control>.Focus() from server side doesn't scroll into view

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Custom Validation Control:

```
<asp:CustomValidator
ID="valSex" runat="server" ErrorMessage="1.2 &lt;b&gt;Sex&lt;/b&gt; not specified"
EnableClientScript="true" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateSex" SetFocusOnError="True">Selection required</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Client Side validation routine:

```
function ValidateSex(source, args) {

    var optMale = document.getElementById("<%=optMale.ClientID %>");
    var optFemale = document.getElementById("<%=optFemale.ClientID %>");

    if (!optMale.checked && !optFemale.checked) {
        args.IsValid = false;
        optMale.focus();
    }
    else
        args.IsValid = true;
}
```

When the page is submitted and Sex is not specified, focus is set but the 2 radio buttons are not quite in view, vertical scrolling is required to bring them into view.

Shouldn't the Focus() method have brought the focus control into view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think all browsers necessarily implement it that way. You can scroll it into view using `scrollTo(x, y)`.

The following should do the trick:

```
function scrollToElement(elementId)
    var offset = findPos(document.getElementById(elementId));
    var x = offset[0];
    var y = offset[1];

    window.scrollTo(x, y);
}

function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);// yes, it's an assignment
    }
    return [curleft,curtop];
}
```

More on finding position at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html.

Comment: I'm thinking that what you posted is probably a round-about way of executing "optMale.scrollIntoView(true);" which didn't seem to work in my web page until I traced through all of the remaining executing javascript and avoided execution of everything else. It appears as though another line of code that is executed later must be causing my problem but there is too much damn script to trace given all the validation controls I'm using. I think I'll start disabling them to narrow it down.

Comment: @George. `scrollIntoView` is not a standard function. However, http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t23 says it should work on most browsers. The function I gave is a little more flexible, but obviously not as simple to use.